# Unable to load type required for deserialization after area change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deserialization

Calling an action yields: "Unable to load type Foobar.Areas.Admin.Models.Templates.DocumentTemplateViewModel required for deserialization."

Strange, becuase that type no longer exists.

It has been moved to: Foobar.Areas.Email.Models.Templates.DocumentTemplateViewModel. The corresponding view and controllers have also been moved to the Email area and everything rebuilt.

I've restarted IIS Express and Visual Studio. No difference.